# How to ignore folder in a folder and read test data?

Tags: python

I am having unsup folder in path `C:/Users/admin/Downloads/aclImdb/train/unsup`. The `train` folder consists of `neg`, `pos`, and `unsup`, each folder containing 12500 `.txt` files. Now the question is I want to exclude the folder `unsup` from reading and store the negative and postive data in a dataset. The following is my code which I have taken:

```
train=[]

exclude =("C:/Users/admin/Downloads/aclImdb/train/unsup")

dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory, topdown=True):

    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for dirs[:] in dirs:
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith("txt"):
                    with open(os.path.join(subdir,file),'r+',encoding="utf8") as data2:
                        train.append(data2.read())
```

The result is as follows:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-4dce3931638b> in <module>()
      7                 if file.endswith("txt"):
      8                     with open(os.path.join(subdir,file),'r+',encoding="utf8") as data2:
----> 9                         train.append(data2.read())
     10
     11

c:\users\varavoorgp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in append(self, other, ignore_index, verify_integrity)
   4433             to_concat = [self, other]
   4434         return concat(to_concat, ignore_index=ignore_index,
-> 4435                       verify_integrity=verify_integrity)
   4436
   4437     def join(self, other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='',

c:\users\varavoorgp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, copy)
   1449                        keys=keys, levels=levels, names=names,
   1450                        verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
-> 1451                        copy=copy)
   1452     return op.get_result()
   1453

c:\users\varavoorgp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy)
   1506         for obj in objs:
   1507             if not isinstance(obj, NDFrame):
-> 1508                 raise TypeError("cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object")
   1509
   1510             # consolidate

TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

By the way I am new to python. I also want to do stemming and lemmenization for this data.

Comment: Note the code for directory is as follows in python   directory=("C:/Users/varavoorgp/Downloads/aclImdb/train")

Comment: So, you did just take (copy and paste) the code frlm somewhere, and you are looking for someone to modify it for you. Without even trying to understand it. I might be wrong (and I apologize if so), but if I'm correct, it is not the way to go. You should spend a bit of time learning python and understanding the code, for your shake and everyone else that will be in contact with your code in the future.

Comment: Dear sir  I just want a simple solution. If you can help with text or data where i can get the same please do. I am as sincere and not robbing of others work. I  am just taking help of study material of others in learning the thing. If you can help me please do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what you want to accomplish and your code has so many problems it doesn't help clarify the situation very much—and I don't even want to try to explain much less fix all the issues it has.

Instead, what's below shows an outline of how to process all the `.txt` files in the subdirectories of a given `directory` while excluding one or more of them. Perhaps it will help.

```
import glob
import os

directory = "C:/Users/varavoorgp/Downloads/aclImdb/train"
exclude = {"unsup",}

for entry in os.listdir(directory):
    entrypath = os.path.join(directory, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(entrypath) and entry not in exclude:
        print('processing subdirectory:', entry)
        for filepath in glob.glob(os.path.join(entrypath, "*.txt")):
            print("  processing file:", filepath)
            # file processing code...
```

Comment: Thanks sir By the method specified I used the additional formula for accessing the files in the pathwith open(os.path.join(filepath),'r+',encoding="utf8") as data2:
                train.append(data2.read())

Comment: Vijay: `with open(filepath,'r+',encoding="utf8") as data2: ...` might work better.